# How do I loop over a list to create a new ID based on list values in R?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have the following data:

```
| parent_sku |  stock_status | regular_price | tax_class | 
|:----------:|:-------------:|:-------------:|:---------:|
| ABBBOA01   |  instock      | 1299          | parent    | 
| ABBBOA03   |  instock      | 1299          | parent    | 
| ABBBOA02   |  instock      | 1299          | parent    | 
| ABBBOA04   |  instock      | 1299          | parent    |
```

I would like to generate four new `sku` for each `parent_sku`, `M`,`L`, `XL` and `XXL`. For example, the above data should be transformed to:

```
| parent_sku |    sku      | stock_status | regular_price | tax_class |    attribute_size   |
|:----------:|:-----------:|:------------:|:-------------:|:---------:|:-------------------:|
| ABBBOA01   | ABBBOA01M   | instock      | 1299          | parent    | M                   |
| ABBBOA01   | ABBBOA01L   | instock      | 1299          | parent    | L                   |
| ABBBOA01   | ABBBOA01X   | instock      | 1299          | parent    | XL                  |
| ABBBOA01   | ABBBOA01XXL | instock      | 1299          | parent    | XXL                 |
| ABBBOA03   | ABBBOA03M   | instock      | 1299          | parent    | M                   |
| ABBBOA03   | ABBBOA03L   | instock      | 1299          | parent    | L                   |
| ABBBOA03   | ABBBOA03XL  | instock      | 1299          | parent    | XL                  |
...
and so on
```

Basically, append the `attribute_size` to the `parent_sku` for each entry.

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65938808/) answer, I've tried doing this:

```
sizes <- c("M", "L", "XL", "XXL")

data <- data %>% mutate(attribute_size = list(sizes)) %>%
  unnest_longer(attribute_size)
data <- data %>% 
      mutate(sku = paste0(parent_sku, list(sizes)))
```

But this just adds `ABBBOA01c("M", "L", "XL", "XXL")` to the sku column. How do I loop over the sizes?  I think this is one of those situations which requires `lapply` but I'm not sure.

Comment: @Wimpel Ahaha no, I'm trying to analyze a dataset I scraped from my Woocommerce website! I'm inexperienced with both.

Comment: `paste0( parent_sku, attribute_size )` in the last line?

Comment: Aye, stupid mistake. Thanks @Wimpel.